# Spring Boot JWT token validation and using claims in microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have two microservices: user service and logic service. I want some paths like login/register from user service to be public, but api of logic microservice to be protected (at least I'm trying to secure it).
The problem is on the logic microservice. So what I want is to take JWT token in that service, validate it (I know a secret key) and save claims to use them later.
I'm testing it like this: getting the token from my user service, then sending the request to my logic service with the token. But the problem is that for whatever reason I get 403, even tho I debugged and it seems like it validates token just fine and even logs the correct claims.
This is my filter:

```
@Slf4j
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final String secretKey;

  public JwtFilter(String secretKey) {
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, FilterChain chain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

   String token = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (token == null || !token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
      return;
    }
    else {
      token = token.substring(7);
      Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
          .setSigningKey(secretKey)
          .parseClaimsJws(token)
          .getBody();

      httpRequest.setAttribute("claims", claims);
      chain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
      log.info(claims.toString());
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

And security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public Filter jwtFilter() {
    return new JwtFilter("...");
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
            auth.requestMatchers("/api/public/**",
                "/v3/api-docs",
                "/v3/api-docs/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
        .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) 
// I also tried to add before BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
        .build();
  }
}
```

But when I try to call the secured api paths with valid jwt token, it answers with 403, even tho it validates the token and even logs correct claims. What could be the problem?
I'm sending the request like this and get 403 response.

```
curl -v -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8080/api/...' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'Authorization: Bearer token'
```

In the debug it logs my claims and then calls BasicErrorController multiple times, nothing more:

```
INFO 12019 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] k.cloudsoft.products.security.JwtFilter  : {claim1=...}
 DEBUG 12019 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
... // Repeats the same call to #error multiple times
```

My controllers are default controllers with no specific security annotations yet. I tried to follow what happens after my filter in the debug, but it just calls multiple filters and then for whatever reason calls error method, it's hard to tell why since the code in there is not easy to understand, so if someone knows how to do it properly, let me know.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I mean, I know for a fact no-one uses sessions and many use JWT, the only real issue is logout, yeah, but many still use it, and it's not the topic of the question

Comment: @Toerktumlare, Sorry, but your rant is not related to the question, I didn't ask if it's normal if I use JWT this way (not in the question, in the answer I just said it's interesting if someone uses it like this, meaning the answer I found), I asked how to do something particular, found an answer and posted it, wym there's no implementation in spring, I literally just posted it, anyways, you don't need oauth eveywhere, for me it's not needed, and for me, if many people use something, than it's ok to use it, so once again, your comments are not related and not needed

Comment: `if many people use something, than it's ok to use it` then now you know why a lot of companies get hacked today this is your quote _But still interested, if it's a normal way to use JWT token between microservices in such way._ and i explained it. What you do with that information is up to you, i hope you are accepting the risks, because they are yours now, all security resources discourage you from using it this way, i have no informed you of that. Good luck

Comment: @Toerktumlare, yeah, you're right, I see that you're trying to help, my bad, I just got defensive because the same question got deleted, now when I found an answer I wasn't letting it be deleted again, but I hear what you're saying, I will explore more possible security precautions, maybe try public/private key JWT scheme additionally

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem by adding instead of

```
httpRequest.setAttribute("claims", claims);
```

this:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(claims.getSubject(), claims.get("..."), authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

But still interested, if it's a normal way to use JWT token between microservices in such way.